# ElasticSearch Nest 7.x AutoSuggest compile error

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, nest

I am trying to create autosuggest query using Nest 7.4 and the example that I found from
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/suggest-usage.html
but I am getting error that Project and ProjectFilter not found . 
Could you please let me know what I am missing .I think Project may refer to the DTO object but that may not be true as I am getting error if I replace the project with DTO

```
void getSuggestions()
        {
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
               .DefaultIndex(index);

            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            var results = client.Search<GenericSearchDto>(new SearchRequest<GenericSearchDto>
                      {
                          Query = ProjectFilter,
                          DocValueFields = Fields<GenericSearchDto>(f => f.Name),
                          Suggest = new SuggestContainer
    {
        {
            "my-term-suggest", new SuggestBucket
            {
                Text = "hello world",
                Term = new TermSuggester
                {
                    MaxEdits = 1,
                    MaxInspections = 2,
                    MaxTermFrequency = 3,
                    MinDocFrequency = 4,
                    MinWordLength = 5,
                    PrefixLength = 6,
                    SuggestMode = SuggestMode.Always,
                    Analyzer = "standard",
                    Field = Field<GenericSearchDto>(p => p.Name),
                    ShardSize = 7,
                    Size = 8
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "my-completion-suggest", new SuggestBucket
            {
                Prefix = Project.Instance.Name,
                Completion = new CompletionSuggester
                {
                    Contexts = new Dictionary<string, IList<ISuggestContextQuery>>
                    {
                        {
                            "color",
                            new List<ISuggestContextQuery>
                                { new SuggestContextQuery { Context = Project.First.Suggest.Contexts.Values.SelectMany(v => v).First() } }
                        }
                    },
                    Fuzzy = new SuggestFuzziness
                    {
                        Fuzziness = Fuzziness.Auto,
                        MinLength = 1,
                        PrefixLength = 2,
                        Transpositions = true,
                        UnicodeAware = false
                    },
                    Analyzer = "simple",
                    Field = Field<GenericSearchDto>(p => p.Suggest),
                    Size = 8,
                    SkipDuplicates = true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "my-phrase-suggest", new SuggestBucket
            {
                Text = "hello world",
                Phrase = new PhraseSuggester
                {
                    Collate = new PhraseSuggestCollate
                    {
                        Query = new PhraseSuggestCollateQuery
                        {
                            Source = "{ \"match\": { \"{{field_name}}\": \"{{suggestion}}\" }}",
                        },
                        Params = new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            { "field_name", "name" }
                        },
                        Prune = true
                    },
                    Confidence = 10.1,
                    DirectGenerator = new List<DirectGenerator>
                    {
                        new DirectGenerator { Field = "description" }
                    },
                    GramSize = 1,
                    Field = "name",
                    RealWordErrorLikelihood = 0.5,
                    TokenLimit = 5,
                    ForceUnigrams = false
                }
            }
```